# Camel AggregationStrategy behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, apache-camel, soa, aggregation

I have a situation where I want to pass data into an [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html), but I don't want the aggregator to do anything until it has received messages from 3 distinct routes:

```
<route id="route-1">
    <from uri="direct:fizz" />

    <to uri="bean:bean1?method=process" />

    <setHeader headerName="id">
        <constant>1</constant>
    </setHeader>

    <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
</route>

<route id="route-2">
    <from uri="direct:buzz" />

    <to uri="bean:bean2?method=process" />

    <setHeader headerName="id">
        <constant>2</constant>
    </setHeader>

    <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
</route>

<route id="route-3">
    <from uri="direct:foo" />

    <to uri="bean:bean3?method=process" />

    <setHeader headerName="id">
        <constant>3</constant>
    </setHeader>

    <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
</route>

<route id="aggregator-route">
    <from uri="direct:aggregator" />

    <aggregate strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy" completionSize="1">
        <correlationExpression>
            <simple>header.id</simple>
        </correlationExpression>
        <to uri="bean:lastBean?method=process" />
    </aggregate>
</route>
```

The way this is configured, when the aggregator's `completionSize` is set to 1 or 2, the aggregated Exchange is routed on to my `lastBean`. However, if I set `completionSize` to 3, for some reason, `lastBean#process` never gets invoked.

I'm **sure** that I'm using `header.id` and the aggregator incorrectly here. In the `correlationExpression`, I just need to make sure that we have 1 Message from each of the 3 routes.

So my question: **what do I need to do to make my aggregator "wait" until it has received 1 message from `route-1`, 1 message from `route-2` and 1 message from `route-3`?**

Comment: A good idea is to study the EIP a bit more to learn how it works. The EIP book, and Camel in Action chapter 8 covers this EIP extensively. As well some docs at: http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are correlating messages from three routes, there needs to be a way for them all to have a matching header.id value by the time they reach the aggregating route.

In your example, each route sets a different id value so there would be no match. If you set the id value to "1" in each route, I think it would start to work as expected.